# NET Core synchronize variable value across Docker service replicas

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-swarm

I am running my .NET Core application in Docker Service, where I have 3 replicas. Application uses **singleton** service added using `services.addSingleton<IMyService>(new MyService());`. In the service, I keep an important variable (let's call it `myVariable`) that I increment when user accesses a certain page. The problem is that `myVariable` is not synchronized across replicas, every replica has its own `MyService` singleton and therefore own value of `myVariable`.

What should I do if I want to keep the value of `myVariable` synchronized across all 3 replicas? I want all replicas to have same value of `myVariable` at any given time. If one replica increases the value, the change should be synchronized across all other replicas.

Comment: if you want to keep the value of `myVariable` synchronized across all 3 replicas - don't store this variable in each of this replicas.

Comment: You probably want some kind of place to store that information - your database, or Redis, for example. Also take a look at [distributed caching in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Since you want a singleton, a static variable is a better option.

Comment: @JohnKennedy do you think that docker services will share a static variable?

Comment: If docker is involved then I can't say for sure, you might need to try it or use some memory store like Redis/Memcache to persist across instances.

Comment: @John I think this is an excellent solution, I will use it. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnKennedy As far as I know docker containers can't share static variables.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo @vasily.sib